# How to implement ContentObserver?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contentobserver

I have a `ContentProvider` , using it I am populating my `ListView`. I need to click one of the `menu-item`. It updates my data sets but i need to reflect the changes in the `ListView`. I read about ContentObserver but i am still confused how to implement it actually. Here is my Code.

**`MYContentObserver`**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class MyObserver extends ContentObserver {        
        public MyObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);            
        }
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            List<Contact> newData;
            if(CONTACT_TYPE == VOIP_CONTACTS){
                newData = ContactsManager.getVoipContacts(getActivity());
            }else{
                newData = ContactsManager.getAllContacts(getActivity());
            }
            customAdapter.contacts().clear();
            customAdapter.contacts().addAll(newData);
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

And I am regsitering it in my onCreate like :

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, true, myObserver);
```

Now What??? Is that is? or I need to call some method etc??

```
**Edite**
```

My `update` method in my content provider is :

```
       @Override
   public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
      int count = 0;
      switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)){
      case CONTACT:
         count = db.update(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, values, 
                 selection, selectionArgs);
         break;
      case CONTACT_ID:
         count = db.update(CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME, values, _ID + 
                 " = " + uri.getPathSegments().get(1) + 
                 (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" +
                 selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
         break;
      default: 
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri );
      }
      getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
      return count;
   }
```

And in my `onOptionItemSelected`, on click of one of the item, m updating like :

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().update(ContactsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, where, null);
```

Comment: yes that's Enough now need to call any method it will register that observer.

Comment: But my app is not entering in onChange/MyObserver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems ok to me, every time your URI `CONTENT_URI` gets updated (insert, delete or modify) your `ContentObserver` should be triggered, if your `onChange()` method is not getting called, make sure that you are pointing to the right URI in your `ContentProvider`.

One thing you should add is the unregister of your content observer, in your `onPause()` method you should do the following:

```
getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(myObserver);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: But my app is not entering in onChange/MyObserver.

Comment: how are you updating your content uri then?

Comment: is your `onUpdate()` method getting called?

Comment: definitely...if i refresh the activity, the lists are updated.

Comment: if you are using loader try calling `restartLoader` in your activity, if not try calling to `myListView.invalidateViews()`

Comment: just to be sure, when you are updating the contact provider you are using `ContactsContentProvider` and when you are registering your `ContentObserver` you are using `MyContentProvider`, are they the same one?